# dissociate firstname/surname by comparing

Tags: python, database, csv

I've a CSV dataset with 2000 rows, with a messy column about first name/surname. In this column I need to dissociate first names and surnames. For that, I've a base with all surnames given in France in the twenty last years.

So, the source database looks like :

```
"name"; "town"
"Johnny Aaaaaa"; "Bordeaux"
"Bbbb Tom";"Paris"
"Ccccc Pierre Dddd" ; "Lyon"
...
```

I want obtain something like :

```
"surname"; "firstname"; "town"
"Aaaaaa"; "Johnny "; "Bordeaux"
"Bbbb"; "Tom"; "Paris"
"Ccccc Dddd" ; "Pierre"; "Lyon"
...
```

And, my reference database of first names :

```
"firstname"; "sex"
"Andre"; "M"
"Bob"; "M"
"Johnny"; "M"
...
```

Technically, I must compare each row from the first base with each field from the second base, in order to identify which character chain correspond to the first name... 
I have no idea about the way to do that.

Any ideas are welcome... thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You can use str.split() to separate the first and last names you have in the first column, but I don't understand the comparison you're trying to do.

Comment: Mmh, ok. I see, sorry for that. The point is that I can't simply separate first and last name because in each line the datas aren't similar. For example : in the first line, I have firstname/surname, but in the second one I have surname/firstname, or in a third ligne only the first letters of the first name, or only a Mr-Mrs/surname... it's a right mess ! So I imagine the comparaison is the only way to get automatically what is a first name and what it's not. At the end, we obtain two colums : one with first names, one with the rest. I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. Finally, I chose the "brute force" approach : each term of each line is compared with the 11.000 keys of my second base (converted in a dictionnary). Not smart, but efficient.

```
for row in input:       
    splitted = row[0].lower().split()       
    for s in splitted :         
        for cle, valeur in dict.items() :       
            if cle == s :                   
                print ("{} >> {}".format(cle, valeur))
```

All ideas about more pretty solutions are still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to

1. Read the data from file say input.csv
2. Extract the name and split it into first name and last name
3. Get the sex using first name
4. And probably write the data again to a new csv or print it.

You can follow the approach as below. You can get more sophisticated in splitting using regex but here is something basic using strip commands:

```
inFile=open('input.csv','r')
rows=inFile.readlines()
newData=[]
if len(rows) > 1:
    for row in rows[1:]:
         #Remove the new line chars at the end of line and split on ;
         data=row.rstrip('\n').split(';')

         #Remove additional spaces in your data
         name=data[0].strip()

         #Get rid of quotes
         name=name.strip('"').split(' ')
         fname=name[1]
         lname=name[0]
         city=data[1].strip()
         city=city.strip('"')

         #Now you can get the sex info from your other database save this in a list to get the sex info later
         sex='M' #replace this with your db calls
         newData.append([fname, lname, sex, city])

inFile.close()
#You can put all of this in the new csv file by something like this (it seperates the fileds using comma):

outFile=open('otput.csv','w')
for row in newData:
    outFile.write(','.join(row))
    outFile.write('\n')
outFile.close(
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Everything is ok, except the step where I split first names and surnames. My principal problem is to separate them, currently randomly mixed in only one field... Thanks again for all this lines, they'll be usefull... after ! :)